# Re-adjust kendo grid row height with jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kendo grid with one column mapped to a varchar table column. The data does not fit in one line so the table cells get wrapped (causing table row to be multi-line).

I also have jquery function that grabs the varchar/string after page load and replaces the value with a shorter substring (makes it one line, instead of multi line). This function is meant to be executed just for certain users - not all users.

```
$('.shortenString').each(function () {
    this.outerHTML = this.innerHTML.substring(0, this.innerHTML.indexOf('-'));
}
```

The problem I am facing is after shortening the string displayed in the column, the entire table row does not re-adjust it's height - the row height stays like the table cell would still be multi-line.

Is there a jquery way to force the kendo grid row(cell) height to be recalculated right after I shorten the table cell string to one line for certain users? I can't set white-space: nowrap for all users on that cell, because I still want the non-shortened text to wrap for some users.

Comment: Can you share the code that is used to shorten the string? Internally, the grid uses HTML elements that should be automatically resized if the content is shortened.

Comment: @CecoMilchev - Yes. I edited my question with the code added.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used kendo grid, but you could try to adjust the table row's height of the shortened table cells, something like this:

```
$('.shortenString').each(function () {
    this.outerHTML = this.innerHTML.substring(0, this.innerHTML.indexOf('-'));
    $(this).closest('tr').prop('height':'30px'); //or whatever height you want
}
```

I haven't seen your table, so I don't know if your rows have multi-line and single line cells in the same row. If that's the case, you could validate it adding more logic to your code.

Anyway, I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I decided to go with a different approach and it turned out I won't need the jquery solution in my fix.